# Socket client using Select

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

Im trying to implement a client function which can establish connection with multiple servers using `select()` function. But I'm not a expert in using `select()` function.
However my client can enable a connection with the multiple servers but it could not able to read messages from those multiple servers.

As per my following example , i connected my client with two servers `( 192.168.100.136, 192.168.100.138)`.
After connected with those two servers , my client was receiving messages from only one server (`192.168.100.136`) , instead of receiving messages from multiple servers..

I'm not sure about the way I used `select()` function in my sample program.
Please correct my sample application to get the desired o/p..
Thanks in advance

```
int main()
{
    int port = 10001 ;
    char ip[][32] = {"192.168.100.136","192.168.100.138"};
    int count = 2 ;
    int ret = clientSelect(ip,port,count);
    return 0 ;
}   
int clientSelect(char **ipAddr ,int port , int count)
    {
    SOCKET max_sd = 0;
    SOCKET socketId[10] = {0};
    SOCKET sd = 0 ;
    SOCKET client_sock[1024] = {0} ;
    fd_set readfds;
    int i ,j , ret;
    char recvBuf[1024] = "";
    char errMsg[256] = "" ;
    struct sockaddr_in server ;

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    // Socket Initialization
    for(i = 0; i<count ; i++)
    {
        ret = initSocket(&socketId[i]);//Small function to create socket
        if (ret != 1)
        {
            return ret ;
        }
        //Server info
        server.sin_addr.s_addr  = inet_addr(ipAddr[i]);
        server.sin_family       = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port         = htons(port);
        // Conect to server
        if (connect(socketId[i], (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
        {
            printf("connect ::Failed to connect to server %s:%d",ipAddr[i],port);
            return -1;
        }
        // Set Socket fd
        FD_SET(socketId[i], &readfds); 

        max_sd = (max_sd>socketId[i])?max_sd:socketId[i];
    }
    while(TRUE)
    {
        ret = select(max_sd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            printf("select failed\n ");
            return -1;
        }
        for ( j = 0 ; j<max_sd ; j++)
        {
            sd = client_sock[j] ;
            if (FD_ISSET(sd, &readfds)) 
            {
                ret = recv(sd,(char *)recvBuf,sizeof(recvBuf), 0);
                if(ret > 0 )
                {
                    printf("Message received from socket %d : %s\n",sd,recvBuf);
                    send(sd,(char *)recvBuf,strlen(recvBuf),0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ret ;

}
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour. Your compiler should complain about missing declaration of `clientSelect` in `main`

Comment: Get rid of the pointless sleep, and handle the cases where `recv()` returns zero or -1 properly, and handle the case where `send()` returns -1 ditto. And `strlen(recvBuf)` should be `ret`. Unclear what you're actually asking.

Comment: And is that C or C++? They are different languages. Pick one!

Comment: My requirement is to implement a client function to connect with multiple servers using select() concept.. I tried to implement as shown in my sample application below.. But I'm not able to get the expected o/p.
My question is , Am i going in a right way to achieve my requirement? 
I know that I did some mistakes in my sample program while using select().. So pls guide me to resolve the issues & help me to get the solution @EJP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fd_set` must be initialized before each use.

Your code should be like:

```
int clientSelect(char **ipAddr ,int port , int count)
{
    SOCKET max_sd = 0;
    SOCKET socketId[10] = {0};
    SOCKET sd = 0 ;

    fd_set readfds;
    int i ,j , ret;
    char recvBuf[1024] = "";
    char errMsg[256] = "" ;
    struct sockaddr_in server ;

    // Socket Initialization
    for(i = 0; i<count ; i++)
    {
        ret = initSocket(&socketId[i]);//Small function to create socket
        if (ret != 1)
        {
            return ret ;
        }
        //Server info
        server.sin_addr.s_addr  = inet_addr(ipAddr[i]);
        server.sin_family       = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port         = htons(port);
        // Conect to server
        if (connect(socketId[i], (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
        {
            printf("connect ::Failed to connect to server %s:%d",ipAddr[i],port);
            return -1;
        }       
    }


    while(TRUE)
    {
        // init fd_set
        FD_ZERO(&readfds); // added by siva to initialize socket descriptors
        for(i = 0; i<count ; i++)
        {
            //FD_ZERO(&readfds); // Commented by siva to avoid initialization for each socket
            FD_SET(socketId[i], &readfds); 
            max_sd = (max_sd>socketId[i])?max_sd:socketId[i];
        }
        ret = select(max_sd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            printf("select failed\n ");
            return -1;
        }
        // warning: you don't know the max_sd value
        for(i = 0; i<count ; i++)
        {
            sd = socketId[i] ;
            if (FD_ISSET(sd, &readfds)) 
            {
                ret = recv(sd,(char *)recvBuf,sizeof(recvBuf), 0);
                if(ret > 0 )
                {
                    printf("Message received from socket %d : %s\n",sd,recvBuf);
                    send(sd,(char *)recvBuf,strlen(recvBuf),0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ret ;

}
```

Comment: Hi , I changed my function as per your suggestion... But still I'm getting messages from only one server rather than receiving messages from both server.... Please guide me further to get the expected o/p.. Actually my requirement is to implement a client function to establish a connection with multiple servers & to monitor the message transaction using select() concept... please correct me , whether i'm going in a right way in my sample function to satisfy the requirement or not...
 @purplepsycho

Comment: Hi  @purplepsycho , I did one small correction in your answer to get the things are working properly as expected... Please correct me , If I did anything wrong in the modification. Thank u